# Rename column in clickhouse with period in name

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I am trying to rename a column to something with a period in the name but haven't been successful so far.

Something like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE x RENAME COLUMN "id" TO "review.id"
```

Fails with:

> DB::Exception: Cannot rename column from nested struct to normal column and vice versa.

Tried the following to escape the period:

1. Escaping period with \ - The backslash is preserved
2. Backticks around name - backticks preserved

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't do that at all. A period is a reserved char on SQL commands in any database. Using a period in a column name will only make things confusing when you start querying and joining this table. In SQL for instance if you have many tables in the same command you can use the table name or an alias and you will need to use the period like `select a.col1, b.col2...... from tablea a, tableb b` naming a column with a period is not only a bad idea is unconventional. Some database will allow you to do so depending on their syntax. Again do not recommend, just stick with a underscore.

Comment: CH uses the dot (period) character for nested columns. You cannot rename normal column to the nested column.

Comment: Thanks @DennyCrane. Is there an alternative approach to rename. I am wondering if creating a new column and copying values of another will work instead.

Comment: Why do you need it? You can use aliases in select. `select id as "x.id" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column with *dot* is used to defining [Nested data structure](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nested-data-structures/nested/).

Use this script to add Nested column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN `review.id` Array(Int32) DEFAULT [id]
```

But take into account that type of this column is *Array(Int32)* not *Int32*:

```sql
┌─id─┬─value─┬─review.id─┐
│  0 │     0 │ [0]       │
│  1 │     2 │ [1]       │
│  2 │     4 │ [2]       │
│  3 │     6 │ [3]       │
..
```

---

To removing the source column follow this way:

```sql
# synchronously materialize the values calculated based on DEFAULT
ALTER TABLE x 
UPDATE `review.id` = `review.id` 
WHERE 1
SETTINGS mutations_sync = 2

# remove DEFAULT expression
ALTER TABLE x MODIFY COLUMN `review.id` REMOVE DEFAULT

# ! check that no rows with uninitialized `review.id`
SELECT * FROM x WHERE `review.id` = []

# drop the source column (! be careful it leads to irrecoverable data loss)
ALTER TABLE x DROP COLUMN id
```

---

Better to avoid dropping the source column but just add alias:

```sql
ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN `review.id` Int32 ALIAS id
```

Comment: This works but you will now have 2 columns and you cannot delete the original id column because the new column depends on it. Good to know about defaulting to a column value though

Answer (score -2):

try this

ALTER TABLE "table_name"
Change "column 1" "column 2" ["Data Type"];

Comment: That is not really Clickhouse syntax. There is no CHANGE